# Why does breaking wood blocks have such a delay in minecraft, and how do I fix?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I have played minecraft avidly in the past, and am quite sure I still know the controls. My problem is, when I start a new game, and start trying to break wood blocks, they break, and almost instantly reappear. It is like I am playing on a laggy minecraft server, except the delay is anywhere between 10 and 20 seconds before the block actually will break, and give me the piece of wood. This is taking all the fun out of playing, so if anyone has an answer to this frustrating problem, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I have had some problems with lag in the past because I didn't have the correct Java version. Maybe check that.

Comment: Are you playing vanilla MC, or with mods?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem and some fixes work while others don't.

**Edit:**
This may be fixed by deleting your .minecraft map (I suggest you make a back-up first so you can copy/paste your worlds back) and then restarting Minecraft via the launcher to re-download everything.

I also found [this](http://cnation.net/cn/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=897) to be helpful.

---

The speed of your Minecraft depends on your FPS, I suggest improving this for faster gameplay.  Here is some [tips](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/game/how-improve-fps-image-3489433/) on how to do this.

I would also suggest using a lag-reducing tool like OptiFine.  This would allow your game to run smoother and hopefully solve the block delay.

Comment: I think this is block lag, not an extreme drop in FPS

Comment: Likely, but might as well try your options.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if you have your render distance too high. Regardless if your computer is powerful enough to handle it, Minecraft behaves weirdly when under stress. Reduce the render distance to at-most 20 blocks and blocks should break as expected.